# Rollback anonymous editor that was probably the OP?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, anonymous-user

I just came across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6204783). It's by an anonymous editor, and removed a bunch of issues with the comment "some problems solved". Presumably, it's by the OP, and they didn't sign in, or a coworker.

Is it worth rollbacking, or just let it slide?

Answer (score 2):

I would say since there are no answers that would be invalidated, don't roll it back. Let it be as long as the question still makes sense and nothing *important and crucial* has been removed through the edit.